# Firebase Rules: What is .contains()?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have read through [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data) and do not understand what is `.contains()`.

Below are the sample rules for Firebase Database in the documentation:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "rooms": {
      "$room_id": {
        "topic": {
          // the room's topic can be changed if the room id has "public" in it
          ".write": "$room_id.contains('public')"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

May I know what is this `$room_id.contains('public')`?

Is it referred to the child of `$room_id`?

Comment: Explained in the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#containssubstring).

Comment: Thanks! for the reference. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$room_id` is the matched wildcard key name that appears as the parent of "topic".  The rule is allowing writes only if that key name contains the string "public" anywhere in it.

So, if anyone tried to change the value of `/rooms/public_roomid/topic` to some value, that would be allowed.  However, a write of `/rooms/roomid/topic` would be rejected.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it now.

Comment: I didn't even know we supported `contains()`. :-)

Comment: you made my day Frank :D

Comment: Can I put auth variable inside contains function?